# Disable core magento module from within modules config.xml

Tags: magento

Is it possible in Magento to disable a core module completely (not just module output) from in a custom modules config.xml?

If so how?

Answer (score 1):

Under /app/etc/modules you have a Mage_Module.xml file
In this file you have a enabled  node with true, set it to false ;)

That's it

Answer (score 0):

Few modules can be disabled but not all.
e.g Mage Core should not be disabled.

Also while disabling any module check if any other module depends on this module.As modules that do depend will also get disabled.

e.g in Mage_Module.xml

```
<Mage_Customer>
    <active>true</active>
    <codePool>core</codePool>
    <depends>
        <Mage_Eav/>
        <Mage_Dataflow/>
        <Mage_Directory/>
    </depends>
</Mage_Customer>
```

change this to

```
<Mage_Customer>
    <active>flase</active>
    <codePool>core</codePool>
    <depends>
        <Mage_Eav/>
        <Mage_Dataflow/>
        <Mage_Directory/>
    </depends>
</Mage_Customer>
```

will disable Customer Module.

Comment: I would rather recommend doing it in `app/etc/module/Your_Own.xml`, just copy over the nodes you want to disable in the same xml structure and and change active to inactive. This way, even if you do an upgrade, your modules won't be re enabled by the update